# How do I write my method for balancing my BST?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So I have written an implementation of a BST in Java. My goal is to make it balanced aswell, more precisly an AVL tree. I am having some problem though, I don't know how to implement the trinodeRestructering method(ie the method that balances the tree) I have tried various things but these pointers are sometimes difficult to deal with and I am not sure how to do this recursivly. Down below is my code for adding a new element and the method to check if we are more than 2 steps difference in the tree.

add and balancing method:

```
private TreeNode insert(TreeNode currN, TreeNode newN) {
    if (currN == null) {
        return newN;
    }

    if (currN.getData() == newN.getData()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value already exists.");
    }

    if (newN.getData() < currN.getData()) {
        if (currN.getLeft() == null) {
            currN.setLeft(newN);

        } else {
            insert(currN.getLeft(), newN);
        }
    } else {
        if (currN.getRight() == null) {
            currN.setRight(newN);

        } else {
            insert(currN.getRight(), newN);
        }
    }

      if (needBalancing()) {
          trinodeRestructering(currN);
      }           

    return currN;
}

private TreeNode trinodeRestructering(TreeNode currN) {
//Not sure what to do here.
    return currN;
}
```

height checking method.

```
    public boolean needBalancing(){
    if(height(root) == -1){ // true if we need to balance
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

private int height(TreeNode node){
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    int left = height(node.getLeft());
    int right = height(node.getRight());

    if (left == -1 || right == -1)
        return -1;

    if (Math.abs(left - right) > 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return Math.max(left, right) + 1;
}
```

I might add that I got an working inOrder method, perhaps I could use it to balance my tree?